# Unable to resolve modules specified in package.json's "exports" field

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, es6-modules

I'm working on a JS web application and am trying to use the `exports` field in a `package.json` file to clean up the import statements for my module.

Here's my directory structure:

```
--> my-package-folder
   --> src
      --> index.js
      --> color
         --> index.js
     --> ui
        --> index.js
```

I would like to be able to import the `color` and `ui` sub-folders like so:

```
import * from '@project/my-package/color'
import * from '@project/my-package/ui'

// Instead of...
// import * from '@project/my-package/src/color/index.js'
// import * from '@project/my-package/src/ui/index.js'
```

Here's a snippet from my package.json:

```
  "name": "@project/my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "./color": "./src/color/index.js",
    "./ui": "./src/ui/index.js"
  },
```

For some reason, I get a 'can't resolve' error when trying to import either the `color` of `ui` sub-folders:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@project/my-package/color'
```

The code that imports `my-package` is still able to import `@project/my-package`, which resolves to `./src/index.js` (specified in the `main` field):

```
import * from '@project/my-package'    // This works
```

It's just importing the `color` and `ui` sub-folders that's a problem.

As a test (just to see what would happen), I removed the `main` field and instead placed its value in the `exports` field:

```
".": "./src/index.js"
```

I figured that if the `exports` field was being read in properly, then this change should still allow importing `@project/my-package` to work. But this actually caused `@project/my-package` to no longer be resolvable.

I noticed that quite a bit of documentation on the `exports` field is geared toward node.js applications. Since I'm not working on a node.js project, I'm wondering if that might have something to do with my issue. Maybe the `exports` field behaves differently when working in a browser.

Is there something else I'm missing? Currently, I'm running the application that's importing `my-package` locally using `webpack-dev-server`. Perhaps something in my webpack config file needs to be updated as well?

Comment: On first glance, can't see the issue, but [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths) is where webpack documents how it resolves packages

Comment: "*Maybe the exports field behaves differently when working in a browser.*" - yes, it's Webpack that needs to implement this, don't look at the nodejs docs. According to https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/ this is supported though, [apparently](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9509) since v5.